# Using IMediaEventSink to post user message (DirectShow) from the pin methods

Tags: c++, directshow

Can DirectShow (Win10, C++) graph elements - pins use IMediaEventSink interface to post own messages (Notify method) ?
For example, in my FillBuffer() implementation I would like to pass information about error occured while receiving data from the external source to the main application extended.
Is it possible to use this interface to do that ?
If yes, how the pin (owner of FillBuffer) can get this interface ?
As I know, the FillBuffer() work in the separate thread. Will the call of the Notify() be thread-safe ?

Answer (score 0):

Your filter class already has a member method [`CBaseFilter::NotifyEvent`](https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/blob/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/baseclasses/amfilter.cpp#L809) to help you with delivery of the event/message.

[Here](https://github.com/roman380/Windows-classic-samples/blob/directshow/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/directshow/filters/synth/dynsrc.cpp#L738) is an example how filter implementation sends an event.

Application is to handle such events in a regular way: [Handle Graph Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/step-6--handle-graph-events).

You don't need to bother abouto additional thread safety, runtime and base class take care of this.